Google App Engine slow cold boot time (Flask app)
I have a problem with Google App Engine that hosts my Flask app.
The Flask app's size iz 60 MB.
The requirements.txt for the app is:
python-bidi>=0.4.2,<0.5.0
Flask
mock
google-auth
pytest
google-cloud-ndb
bcrypt
google-cloud-tasks
google-cloud-storage
bleach
openpyxl
pandas
xlrd
protobuf<4.0.0dev,>=3.15.0
xmltodict
stripe
cryptography
pycountry
openai
PyPDF2
deep_translator
reportlab
xhtml2pdf
google-api-python-client
google-auth-httplib2
google-auth-oauthlib
oauth2client
werkzeug>=2
requests>=2,<3
identity>=0.5.1,<0.6

The app is used for converting files from CSV to XML, and also it's using some API endpoints to retrieve data and covert it to XML and PDF.
So anyways, the problem is that the cold boot start of an instance on Google App Engine is taking 40 seconds and sometimes even more. The instance class for GAE is: F4_1G
The scaling of instances is automatic in app.yaml
Warmup requests are enabled.
App is using Python 3.9
Logging example of a cold boot start:

Logging after the request:

Stack trace:

I don't see anything useful from the stack trace, it just displays that the loading took 40 seconds.
After the cold start is done, then the responses are fast (average 40ms).
Any help would be appreciated, I have tried numerous fixes but nothing worked (warmup requests, reducing required libraries, I can't select a smaller instance class because then the memory is too low).
I can also provide more screenshots/information if needed.

You may want to try Profiling your app. I'm less familiar with profiling Python apps but this should give you a view over time of CPU and memory and may give you some indication as to what's being done during the mysterious 40 seconds. Is a larger instance size (much) faster? Does the app take as long to boot when run locally? etc. etc.

It isn't enough to enable warmup requests. The handler should actually do something that will help speed up your app load process e.g fetch and cache application data. Did you do something like this? Is your App written in such a way that libraries are only loaded, computation done, variables initialized only when they're needed? E.g. do them when user makes a call to a handler and not when your application starts?

From the docs if your app is serving no traffic, the first request to the app will always be a loading request, not a warmup request. This is another indicator that warmup requests on its own might not be enough. How your App is written (see my previous comment) will then come into play.

I'm curious as to why you have google-api-python-client when you have cloud libraries (cloud ndb, cloud task, cloud storage). The Github page for google-api-python-client does say that folks should rather be using the cloud client libraries

@NoCommandLine thanks for all your information. I did some tests and found out that the main problem is probably how big the app is. The app currently has 403 routes in the main.py file. Each of those routes then call the handler that handles the route to the user. Handlers also use models for Datastore models. When I removed 3/4 of the routes and import statements, the app loaded a lot faster. Do you have any recommendations on how to speed up a Flask app (maybe changing the structure, so not everything is loaded at the start)? I will also try and remove google-api-python-client

I didn't expect the number of routes to be an issue because my understanding is that a route is only called when it's invoked. Normally, I would say only run functions when they're needed and not as part of starting up the app (globally) e.g if you were currently initializing cloud storage stuff once your app starts, move it to when a route handler which needs the cloud storage stuff is called. This would also apply to importing packages/libraries.

I solved this issue using Flask Lazy loading views. Rather than importing everything in your main application .py file, just use lazy loading. This got my Flask app cold boot loading from 37 seconds down to 6-8 seconds. This doc helped me solve it:
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/stable/patterns/lazyloading/
This is an example. So this is how the code used to be in main.py (main Flask app file where the routes are set and the app.run() is located):
from handlers.profile import profile_main

app.add_url_rule(rule="/profile", view_func=profile_main, methods=["GET"])

And this is the new way, using lazy loading:
from utils.lazy_loading_handlers import LazyView

app.add_url_rule(rule="/profile", view_func=LazyView('handlers.profile.profile_main'), methods=["GET"])

The LazyView function looks like this:
from werkzeug.utils import import_string, cached_property


class LazyView(object):
    def __init__(self, import_name):
        self.__module__, self.__name__ = import_name.rsplit('.', 1)
        self.import_name = import_name

    @cached_property
    def view(self):
        return import_string(self.import_name)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.view(*args, **kwargs)

So essentially what we are doing is, importing handlers after they are needed (ie. when the route is called) and not when the app is starting. This also saves on memory consumption. Before, the app was using 1600MB of memory, now when it starts up, only 460MB of memory.
This is because not all libraries are loaded. They are loaded only when needed.
The only downside to this is:
The first time you open a route after the app started from cold boot, the response time could be around 2-4 seconds. This is because, before we were already initializing everything when the app started, but now it will only start initializing a handler once needed.
But either way, I think this is the only normal way to run a Flask app on Google App Engine... You can't have customers wait for 37 seconds for the app to fully load, that is just ridiculous.

Please give an example of a code that implements lazy loading, otherwise your answer won't be useful anymore if the link becomes dead.

@Titouan thanks for mentioning. I have edited the post which now has all needed details.

I agree with @DazWilkin, that you would need to profile your application to figure out exactly what’s going on and if/what can be done to significantly improve it.
If warmup requests aren't enough, the typical way is setting the min_idle_instances to 1 in the app.yaml’s scalability configurations to minimize the impact of cold start times.
Hope this helps!

Thanks for your answer! I have followed @DazWilkin and your advice to profile the app. I put the profiling function call into my main.py where the app is initialized. The profiler did not provide much details, at least I don't think so. This is a profiler from the last hour, where there was a cold boot request which took around 40 seconds to process. This is the image of the profiler: link As you can see the image displays 47 ms time, which has no correlation with 40 seconds of loading time. Wall time: link

Hi Jan. If setting the min_idle_instances to 1 in the app.yaml scaling configuration didn’t resolve the issue, you may want to try the Custom Tracing metrics by leveraging the Stackdriver Trace API. This API allows you to patch the existing traces generated by App Engine with your own data, so that it’ll all show up in one nice place. For more details, see Colt McAnlis's article, Understanding and Profiling App Engine Cold-Boot Time.
